# How to extract parasitic capacitance of an oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope, probe, parasitic-capacitance

Can someone please explain the procedure to extract the parasitic capacitance of an oscilloscope? I have seen that the contribution of probe capacitance is 3.9 pF. The scope is a Tektronix 3 series MDO.

Comment: Read the capacitance value written on the front of the oscilloscope.

Comment: Or rather, read the data sheet of the probe to find probe capacitance.

Comment: probe capacitance is given 3.9pF. I am skeptical if this is the parasitic capacitance.

Comment: Some probes ... https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/7018-01494/technical-overviews/5989-6162.pdf